# Unable to see embedded image in <TextArea> using <img> tag (Flex 3.5 build 123683)

Tags: html, image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe

Note: Yes, I'm aware that adobe flex docs inform that 'The  tag is not fully supported, and might not work in some cases.'

Here is the mx.Controls.TextArea declaration...

```
<mx:TextArea id="bannerText" width="100%" height="100%" fontSize="12"
             backgroundColor="#FAA7B0" paddingLeft="15" borderStyle="none"
             textAlign="left" themeColor="#FAA7B0" htmlText="{bannerHtmlText}"/>
```

I am successfully pulling the html formatted text from a file located on a server and then successfully displaying that text in my  using 'htmlText="{nameOfStringToWhichHTMLIsAssigned}"'. Flex is displaying the html perfectly with the exception of the portion of html formatted text which is supposed to embed an image from a URL.

Here is the html...

```
\r\n  <html>\r\n  <body>\r\n  To see the latest updates from MySmartPlans <a href="http://info.mysmartplans.com">Click Here!</a>\r\n  <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>\r\n  <img src='https://www.dummy.com/images/MSP_newlogo_RGB.jpg' alt='MySmartPlans' width='200' height='43'>\r\n  </body>\r\n  </html>\r\n
```

When the html text is displayed, There seems to be some invisible content where the image should be. I say that because, I am able to select/highlight four or five lines of text that are otherwise invisible.

I have looked over similar queries in stackoverflow but they all seem to deal with hard coded image URL's inside of the  tag i.e...

```
<mx:TextArea xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
            [Embed(source='../assets/img.gif')]
            public var img:Class;
         ]]>
    </mx:Script>
 </mx:TextArea>
```

I am unable to hard code the URL in there like that.

If there is some sort of hack (way around this) I would be greatful for the assistance!!
 Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you convert your image to a PNG?  It's not a guaranteed fix, but it's the first thing that occurs to me.

Comment: @Brian Are you suggesting that I use the PNG image format for the images stored on the server (the source for the images I will be using) or accessing the image, in current JPEG format, in the ActionScript and then converting it to PNG and then attempting to display it?

Comment: I meant try loading a PNG from your server.